# Unexpected namespace prefix "app" found for tag RelativeLayout - Android?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, bottom-sheet

I need to use `BottomSheetBehavior` with `ScrollView` but it says to me :

```
Unexpected namespace prefix "app" found for tag RelativeLayout

app:behavior_hideable="true"
app:behavior_peekHeight="80dp"
```

Here is my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/ABLList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imbDetail"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_detail" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_OrderList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ABLList"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_bottom_sheet_ListOrder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="@color/color_bottom_sheet"
            android:gravity="top"
            app:behavior_hideable="true"
            app:behavior_peekHeight="80dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/string_bottom_sheet_behavior">

            <com.example.asheq.utils.TextViewJus
                android:id="@+id/txtAddress"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/text_marginTop"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:maxLines="5"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSReport"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtCTime"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:text="@string/btnReport" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorOrder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: For someone who get the error `Unexpected namespace prefix “app” found` for textView, you might need to change `TextView` to `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView`

Comment: @林果皞 I think you can add that as an answer since seems like you're the only one that's really answering the answer.

Answer (score 17):

This issue is well known in while using **data-binding** in a layout.

Assume you want to use some data binding attribute with `app:` prefix then just adding `xmlns:app...` will not be enough. layout should be data binding layout **wrapped with `<layout` tag**.

## Incorrect Approach:

e.g. I imported `layout_toolbar_default.xml` and using `app:toolbarTitle` to specify `title`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <include
        layout="@layout/layout_toolbar_default"
        app:toolbarTitle="@{@string/app_name}"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**This will show error `Unexpected namespace prefix "app" found`**.

## Solution:

Wrap your layout with `<layout` tag because you are using binding attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <include
            layout="@layout/layout_toolbar_default"
            app:toolbarTitle="@{@string/app_name}"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: This works to get rid of the error, but fails if the file is inflated on its own.

Comment: @Kenny I did not get `if the file is inflated on its own`

Comment: when I tried the <layout> on the top level of a layout file, and inflated that layout file directly it LayoutInflater.inflate would throw an exception, but worked fine when the layout was used as an include.

Comment: You mean, you can't inflate data binding layout directly?

Comment: Its more than a data binding layout, but yes.

Comment: This solves my issue with it breaking, but now it doesn't show the variable in my TextView, even though everything else passes

Comment: I am not using Data Binding

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. Just take out your bottom-sheet layout into the separate file. And include it in the main layout via `include` tag.

Answer (score 6):

Use of **android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:behavior_hideable="true"
            app:behavior_peekHeight="80dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/string_bottom_sheet_behavior">

</android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Comment: It is better to use AndroidX libraries now.

Answer (score 5):

For people using androidx, if you have child views from some androidx view, they should also be the androidx view to be able to recognize app namespace prefix. For example instead of:

`<ImageView/>` you should use `<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView/>`

This is not harmfull and it provides support for lower api version if you use some features that could not be supported (like tints for ImageView) :)

Answer (score 2):

Try setting your `xmlns` namespace once in the parent layout if you are going to use it multiple times.

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Writing this declaration once in your parent `CoordinatorLayout` will suffice.

Hint: When using multiple layouts and views, try to implement the `<include/>` attribute. It will make your code clean and easily readable.

Answer (score 1):

For someone who gets the similar error `Unexpected namespace prefix “app” found` on textView, you might need to change `TextView` to `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView`.

Comment: A documentation of AppCompatTextView says: `You should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views.`

Comment: To whom downvote, you should know what's the meaning of `you might` (because of custom views), neither `you must` nor `you should`.

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

This is set multiple times. Both in `CoordinatorLayout` and `RelativeLayout`.
Remove the one in `RelativeLayout`.
Declaring once in the file will suffice.