# How does BottomSheetBehavior_Layout_behavior_hideable get translated to app:behavior_hideable?

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

In the Android documentation for [BottomSheetBehavior](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior#attr_BottomSheetBehavior_Layout_behavior_hideable), it says I can use the following attribute in XML:

```
BottomSheetBehavior_Layout_behavior_hideable
```

I tried this:

```
android:BottomSheetBehavior_Layout_behavior_hideable="true"
```

But that gave me the following error:

> Unknown attribute android:BottomSheetBehavior_Layout_behavior_hideable

That error is discussed at [Unknown attribute android:layout_width, layout_height, id, gravity, layout_gravity, padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35308735/unknown-attribute-androidlayout-width-layout-height-id-gravity-layout-gravi) but none of those solutions worked for me because they were about syncing project files.  Mine are synced.  Nobody questioned the validity of the attribute name, which is what I think is my problem here.

Then I tried this:

```
app:BottomSheetBehavior_Layout_behavior_hideable="true"
```

But that gave me the following error:

> Unexpected namespace prefix "app" found for tag

That error is discussed at [Unexpected namespace prefix "app" found for tag RelativeLayout - Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40972522/unexpected-namespace-prefix-app-found-for-tag-relativelayout-android) but none of those solutions worked for me, and--more central to my question--there the attribute seems to be written like this:

```
app:behavior_hideable="true"
```

Is `app:behavior_hideable` the correct way to write `BottomSheetBehavior_Layout_behavior_hideable`?  What is the name of the mechanism that performs this translation?  Where is its documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of components to the answer.

1. In the constructor for a `BottomSheetBehavior`, xml attributes are read out as follows [Source](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetBehavior.java#L191):

`TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.BottomSheetBehavior_Layout);
setHideable(a.getBoolean(R.styleable.BottomSheetBehavior_Layout_behavior_hideable, false));`

2. These attributes are typically defined in an `attrs.xml file`.  Here's the [attrs.xml](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/res/values/attrs.xml#L24) for the BottomSheetBehavior.

So what's happening here is a `LayoutInflater` is calling the constructor, and xml attributes are accessed via `R.styleable.[name_of_style]_[name_of_attribute]`.  When you want to apply the style in xml, you simply use the name of the attribute.  In the case, the name of the style is "BottomSheetBehavior_Layout", and the name of the attribute is "behavior_hideable".  Similarly, you could also use "behavior_skipCollapsed" and "behavior_fitToContents".

For more information on styling, the official docs are here: https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view#customattr

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful information.  So is `app:` the proper prefix?  From the official docs link you provided, I can tell that `android:` is not the proper prefix because it says "Instead of belonging to the http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android namespace, they belong to http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/[your package name]." However, why would `app:` be the proper namespace if I didn't create https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/res/values/attrs.xml#L24 ? What is the right namespace?

Comment: @MichaelOsofsky Here's a good answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26692768/3781068.  Basically because `BottomSheetBehavior` is in the support library and not "vanilla android", it uses the app namespace.  So in general, if it's made available via a gradle dependency, you need to use `app:`, otherwise fall back to `android:`